# eregi_replace replacement

Tags: regex, preg-replace, eregi

I'm pretty naff with regexpressions :( and I have inherited a bunch of code from a previous developer who has put lots of eregi_replace which are now deprecated on PHP 5.3

The functions in the code are:

```
eregi_replace("[\]","",$text);
```

I know I have to replace this function with preg_replace but I'm not sure what to do to "[]" in order to make it perl compatible.

I've tried "/[]/" but that gets a compilation error in PHP error log.

Many thanks

Comment: `[]` is not required since `[]` means match any character within it only 1 time..it should be \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eregi_replace`, this function has been **DEPRECATED** as of PHP 5.3.0.
Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

---

[`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) - Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string
[`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) - Perform a regular expression search and replace

---

```
str_replace("\", "", $text);
```